# Access video resource from file system in Java Spring web application

Tags: java, html, video, web-applications, resources

From my Java Spring web application I need **access video resource** which is on **file system** (outside of the application). I would like to access it via URL on HTML (preferably using HTML 5 tag ).

I found some simple servlets. But is it a safe way? Will video player work adequately (e.g. stop video, jump etc.)?

What is the best (and easy) way how to access video resource in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Did you give your 'simple servlets' found a try?

Comment: Not yet. I believe that there is a better solution which solves possible error states and is safer (I am a little worried to access something on file system from web app)... I think that servlets on 10-20 lines are not the "full" solution and I hope that there is some proven solution.

Comment: For example I found **aliases from Tomcat 7** - http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/3904871/Top-7-Features-in-Tomcat-7-The-New-and-the-Improved.htm. 

Unfortunately, I don't want to depend on a server solution. I believe that there should be other possibilities. **Any suggestion?** Something in Spring or anything else?